# Why doesn't this ?: operator return null?

Tags: c#, null, operators, conditional-statements

I wrote this line of code to handle nulls but I still get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error whenever I run this line of code when expectedItem is null. What gives? What's the proper way to write this?
Since expectedItem is null, I'd expect expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount to be null also so this statement should assign an empty string to x.

```
string x = expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount != null ? expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount : "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check both the object instance (expectedItem) and the property (expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount) as either may fail:

```
string x = expectedItem != null && expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount != null ? expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount : "";
```

Comment: I'm picking this one because it checks both the object and its property and I like this syntax style

Comment: really? I find reading multiple nested ternary operators hard on the eyes.

Comment: @FlavorScape, I agree, but I wrote it in the same fashion as the OP posted in the question.

Comment: @FlavorScape, Which of the styles in the answers would you use or do you have a specific style to share? Thanks in advance

Comment: @activwerx Which of the styles in the answers would you use or do you have a specific style to share? Thanks in advance

Comment: @starvingPhilosopher it's all down to personal preference, I will add another answer for you to look at

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if `expectedItem` is not null, not its property

```
string x = expectedItem != null ? expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount : "";
```

Comment: should the op not check both the object instance and its property? see my answer.

Comment: @activwerx: if they should - they will find this out soon ;-) Doing mistakes is the best way to learn

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is wrong.  try

```
string x = expectedItem == null ? "" : expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount != null ? expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount : "";
```

Comment: +1 same as the selected answer, and you were first by several minutes

Answer (score 1):

expcetedItem is no doubt null:

```
string x;

if (expectedItem != null)
    x = expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount != null ? expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: you're dereferencing `expectedItem` because you're checking `expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount` for null rather than checking `expectedItem` itself.  You should probably write

```
string x = expectedItem != null ? expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

expectedItem is null.

```
if( expectedItem != null)
  x = expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount != null ? expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount : "";
else 
  x = "poop";
```

Comment: You can't say `if (expecteditem)` in C#; you have to explicitly compare it to null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string x = expectedItem != null && expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount != null
    ? expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount
    : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to write your code is as follows:

```
string x = expectedItem != null ? (expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount != null ? expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount : "") : "";
```

You first have to make sure expectedItem is not null, if it is you would have an illegal operation called [null pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#Null_pointer); you should then assign *x* an empty string.

If it is not null, and you write it like this

```
string x = expectedItem != null ? expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount : "";
```

x could be either null or *expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount*, if you don't want *x* to be null, for instance, you would make string operations on it later such as Compare or Concat, you should also make sure its member ExpectedResultAmount is not null either.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been suggested the the accepted answer is "*not easy on the eye*", you might also consider this:

```
string x = ""; //string is empty...
if (expectedItem != null && expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount != null)
{
    x = expectedItem.ExpectedResultAmount; //...unless this exists.
}
```

Comment: It may be a 5 line (as opposed to my 1 line) solution, but it's very easy to read!